# How can i check the proxy settings done by 'System.setProperty' in Java?

Tags: java, proxy

i'm developing an Java application that will be used to launch some Test Automation scripts on dedicated environment.
It is required to set also the proxy when necessary.
I developed a class that will be used to configure the proxy settings once a properties read from external contains the flag 'ENABLE_PROXY' equals 'True'.

Following is my snippet code:

```
    package proxy;

import java.io.InputStream;
import java.net.HttpURLConnection;
import java.net.URL;
import java.util.Properties;

import org.apache.commons.lang3.exception.ExceptionUtils;

public class ProxyConfiguration {

    private static String proxyHost;
    private static String proxyPort; //80 if it isn't provided
    private static String nonProxyHosts;
    private static String protocolType;
    public static boolean flagProxy;

    //Set method used to read the flag Proxy
    public static boolean isProxyEnabled(Properties myPropertiesFile) {
        flagProxy = Boolean.parseBoolean(myPropertiesFile.getProperty("ENABLE_PROXY").toLowerCase());
        return flagProxy;
    }

    public static String getProxyHost() {
        return proxyHost;
    }

    //Set method used to read the Proxy host from properties
    public static void setProxyHost(Properties myPropertiesFile) {
        ProxyConfiguration.proxyHost = myPropertiesFile.getProperty("PROXY_HOST");
    }

    public static String getProxyPort() {
        return proxyPort;
    }

    //Set method used to read the Proxy port from properties
    public static void setProxyPort(Properties myPropertiesFile) {
        ProxyConfiguration.proxyPort = myPropertiesFile.getProperty("PROXY_PORT");
    }

    public static String getNonProxyHosts() {
        return nonProxyHosts.replace(",", "|");
    }

    //Set method used to read the exception from properties
    public static void setNonProxyHosts(Properties myPropertiesFile) {
        ProxyConfiguration.nonProxyHosts = myPropertiesFile.getProperty("PROXY_EXCEPTION");
    }
    
    public static String getProtocolType() {
        return protocolType;
    }

    //Set method used to read the exception from properties
    public static void setProtocolType(Properties myPropertiesFile) {
        ProxyConfiguration.protocolType = myPropertiesFile.getProperty("PROTOCOL_TYPE");
    }
    
    //Method used to set the Proxy settings on system
    public static void setProxyConfiguration(Properties myPropertiesFile) {

        try {
            ProxyConfiguration.setProtocolType(myPropertiesFile);
            ProxyConfiguration.setProxyHost(myPropertiesFile);
            ProxyConfiguration.setProxyPort(myPropertiesFile);
            ProxyConfiguration.setNonProxyHosts(myPropertiesFile);
            
            System.setProperty("java.net.useSystemProxies", "true");
            System.setProperty(ProxyConfiguration.getProtocolType() +".proxyHost", ProxyConfiguration.getProxyHost());
            System.setProperty(ProxyConfiguration.getProtocolType() +".proxyPort", ProxyConfiguration.getProxyPort());

            boolean exceptions = ProxyConfiguration.getNonProxyHosts().isEmpty();
            if(!exceptions) {
                System.setProperty(ProxyConfiguration.getProtocolType() +".nonProxyHosts", ProxyConfiguration.getNonProxyHosts());
            }
            try {
                URL url = new URL("http://java.sun.com/");
                InputStream in = url.openStream();
                //return true;
            } catch (Exception e) {
                //return false;
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.err.println("Si è verificato un errore nella setProxyConfiguration: ");
            String exc = ExceptionUtils.getStackTrace(e);
            System.err.println(exc);
            System.exit(-1);
        }
    }
}
```

**How can i check if the proxy settings are set correctly?**

I tried also to used the command prompt of my local machine and launch the follwing command:

- netsh winhttp show proxy

but i receive:

```
Current WinHTTP proxy settings:

Direct access (no proxy server).
```

The properties read are:

- PROTOCOL_TYPE=http
- PROXY_HOST=webcache.mydomain.com (it is an example found on [Java Networking](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/guides/net/proxies.html))
- PROXY_PORT=8080
- PROXY_EXCEPTION=

Thanks for supporting!

Comment: You can check the result of `System.getProperty()` with `System.getProperty()`. You can check whether it actually works by trying to use it. Unclear what you're asking.

Comment: Thanks for answer me! Probably i don't know what really do the method 'System.setProperty'. I thought that is will set the proxy directly on the local machine and i can check it from cmd. Is it wrong?